# How to add dynamic data to pdf header using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to generate a pdf using itextsharp.i must add some dynamic data to pdf header.how can i do this in onpagestart event.

Comment: What do you mean by "PDF header"? Are you talking meta data or the top of a page?

Answer (score 2):

You can always declare your variable in your own implementation of IPdfPageEvent interface. You will then have the ability to set the value of that variable anywhere outside of your IPdfPageEvent implementation.

Say

```
writer.PageEvent.variable = "Some value";
```

Using OnStartPage event, you can do something like:

```
public class MyPageEvent:IPdfPageEvent
{
  public string variable="";
 public void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
 {
       PdfContentByte cb = riter.DirectContent;;
       cb.BeginText();
       cb.SetFontAndSize(myBaseFont, 10f);
       cb.SetTextMatrix(600, 15);
       cb.ShowText(this.variable);
       cb.EndText();
 }
 ......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need an answer, but what I'm currently doing is casting my pdfwriter.pageevent object down to the explicit subclass, then setting a public property in that subclass.

in the class generating the PDF:

```
 CType(pdfWriter.PageEvent, PDFDocEventHelper).currentValue = value
```

and the subclassed PdfPageEventHelper class:

```
Public Class PDFDocEventHelper
 Inherits PdfPageEventHelper

 Public Property currentValue as String
 .
 .
 .
 End Class
```

make sense? I'm not at all fond of casting down using CType() but it does seem to work.